# Why present perfect and not simple past in this sentence?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions

Cold you please help me?

I have tried to find an explanation, but I am stuck.

I watched an interview yesterday. Both people were sitting in a garden and at a certain point the interviewee pointed at a meadow and said: "This tatty patch of unkempt former lawn has given me an enormous joy *this spring*."
What confuses me is at the moment of the interview it was clearly summer so why is this right? When I say "this morning" and it is afternoon I have to use the simple past, right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you've correctly transcribed it, I don't think he's a native speaker (almost no native speaker would include the article with ***an** enormous joy* here). But using Present Perfect is perfectly natural, since it reflects the fact that the speaker is still happy ***now***. Consider a similar usage such as *I have only smoked two cigarettes this morning.* There's nothing wrong with saying that after midday - or even *later that same evening*, if the statement continues to have relevance to time of utterance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason it sounds OK to me is because the "now" in question is "this year".

In "my lawn has given me enormous joy this spring", spring is still "now" in the sense that it is still this year.  In contrast "my lawn has given me enormous joy last spring" does sound odd.

For that reason, if you want to emphasize the fact that it was this year, rather than in a past unit of time (and maybe even over and done with), "has given" works better.

@FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica 's interpretation is plausible: maybe the speaker thinks of themselves as still happy about it right now.  But maybe they are just thinking of today as part of this year for some other reason: for example, maybe they're comparing it to last year, when they had no lawn?  Or maybe "gave me" would sound to them too much like it's never going to give them joy again?